# Get This Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing

**I get Error with my code
This is my code :**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {
        for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(mainframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            new mainframe().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I doubt very much that the above code is triggering your problem.  The exception's stack trace should lead to the point in your code that is causing the error. And as a personal preference, I'd use `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName())`, unless you specifically need a particular look and feel (like old windows)

Comment: Never catch exceptions without handle it. At least log it

Comment: Jazakallahu khair, Thank You Very Much Brother @MadProgrammer and Jens